# Split the file in java and process it

Tags: java

I have a file with hundreds of thousands of lines. I want to process every 100 lines in java code

Example- file of 250 lines

- 1st iteration 0-100 lines
- 2nd iteration 101-200 lines and
- finally last iteration should process remaining lines - 201 - 250.

I did with for loop, but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Show us your code, then we might help. "it didnt work in my case" is also highly unspecific.

Comment: The basic idea is simple: read the file line by line in a loop, trigger processing after every x lines and after the loop trigger processing again for the last batch (if the total number of lines isn't a multiple of x which is quite likely in most cases).

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at `Files.lines(Path)` (available from Java 8). It returns a `Stream<String>` from a file. As a result, you do not need to split the file anymore.

Comment: Kindly be more specific.

Comment: br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infilename));
     int lines = 0;
     while (br.readLine() != null) lines++;
     if(lines % 10 == 0)
     {
      count = 10;
     }
     else
     {
      count = lines % 10;
     }
     System.out.println("count "+count);
     for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
     while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
      
      line +=line+"\n";
      
      System.out.println(line);
     }
     }

Comment: Don't post code in comments.Use the edit link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer below does not depend on Java 8. The idea below is simply to loop through each line and then have a block counter that increments every 100 lines.

```
InputStream in = ...
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line = null;
int idx = 0;
int blockIdx = 0
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (idx % 100 == 0) {
        blockIdx++;
    }
    idx++;
}
```